# Flex DateChooser: how to override the 'today' date?

Tags: apache-flex

By default, the Flex DateChooser highlights the 'today' date. I assume it gets this date from the OS. Is there a way to tell DateChooser what the 'today' date should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the source code of `mx.controls.CalendarLayout` (which is used internally by `DateChooser`):

```
// Determine whether this month contains today.
var today:Date = new Date();
var currentMonthContainsToday:Boolean = (today.getFullYear() == newYear && today.getMonth() == newMonth);
```

it seems that you have no influence on this. You could, of couse, extend/replace the `DateChooser` and `CalendarLayout` classes, and override the relevant functions.

Comment: +1 think extending the CalendarLayout class would be a tough job though. CalenderLayout is enormous and it's probably very easy to break

Comment: @James: agreed. Still, I guess this is the only option if one really wants to change "today".